# Find a Cook Reduction from $R_{Clique}$ to its determinist problem

Tags: algorithms, reductions, np, clique

The question is to find Find a Cook Reduction from $R_{k-Clique}$ to its determinist problem.

Basically:

k-Clique: a group of $k$ nodes in the graph such there is an edge between every two nodes.

Suppose you are allowed to use an algorithm (B) that in $O(1)$, given as input a graph $G$ and a number $k$, returns whether the graph includes a $k-Clique$ or not.

Use B to define an algorithm (A), that in polynomial time, given as input a graph $G$ and a number $k$, returns a $k-Clique$ if it exists, and a symbol if it doesn't.

My idea:

My idea was to define something as follow:

```
1. While the size of the graph is greater than k
    2. Remove from the graph the node with the lowest deg
        1. check the new G with B, if yes, return it
        2. Else, continue
```

Something like that. I wasn't able to disprove it at least. But is it correct? How would I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm doesn't return a $k$-clique. Simply consider a connected graph $G$ that is a proper supergraph of a $k$-clique, and an isolated vertex $x$. Your algorithm with input $G+x$ returns $G$.

You can solve your problem as follows:

- While $\exists $ a vertex $v$ of $G$ such that $B(G-v)$ returns true:

  - Delete $v$ from $G$
- Return $G$.

Let $G^* = (V^*, E^*)$ be the graph returned by the algorithm.
Since the algorithm preserves the invariant "G contains a $k$-clique", $G^*$ must also contain a $k$-clique. This means that we only need to prove that $G^*$ is not a supergraph of a $k$-clique.

Suppose towards a contradiction that there exists a proper subset $C$ of $V^*$ such that $|C|=k$ and the subgraph of $G^*$ induced by $C$ is a $k$-clique. Then, for any vertex in $v \in V^* \setminus C \neq \emptyset$,  $G-v$ also contains a $k$-clique. This shows that the algorithm cannot return $G^*$ and yields the sought contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand your algorithm and proof, but I have two questions: 
1. Notice how my algorithm runs "While the size of the graph is greater than k", so in your initial example I don't think I would return $G$: I would continue to run. 
2. What is the time complexity of your algorithm? Is it polynomial?
We repeat it $k$ times, each time I have to remove an edge and do the check, for $G-i$ nodes

Comment: Your algorithm says: "1 While the size of the graph is greater than $k$. In my case it is, so we proceed to step 1.2. Step 1.2 is "Remove from the graph the node with the lowest degree", so we remove $x$ from the input graph $G+x$ and we are left with $G$. The next instruction is 1.2.1:  "Check the new G with B, if yes, return it". The new graph is $G$ and contains a $k$-clique, so $B$ returns "yes", and your algorithm returns $G$. However $G$ is not a $k$-clique (it just contains it).

Comment: My algorithm does run in polynomial time. A trivial implementation evaluates the condition of the while loop at most $n-k+1$ times. Each evaluation runs $B$ $O(n)$ times. A better analysis uses the fact that if a vertex cannot be removed in one iteration, then it belongs to **all** $k$-cliques of $G$ and hence it won't be removed in any following iterations. Therefore $n$ iterations suffice. To summarize, you can just consider one vertex $v \in V$ at a time and do the following: if $B(G-v)$ returns true then delete $v$ from $G$. Once all vertices $v$ have been considered, return $G$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!